# creating and run your own algorithms on localized map

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

So here is my problem. I plan to implement a localized map for my college presenting all the locations such as main block, Tech park etc. 
 Not only do i plan to develop a GUI but also I also want to run my own algorithms, such as finding the quickest route from one block to another etc (Note: the algorithm is something i will be writing since i don't want to take the **shortest** route as the **quickest** but want to add my own parameters as weights). 
 I want to host the map locally (say on a in house system) and should be able to cater real time request (displaying route to the nearest cafeteria) and display current data (such as what event is taking place in what corner of the campus). 
I know Google Maps API or Openstreetmap/OpenLyers API will enable me to build my own map, but can i run my own algorithms on them? also can I add elements that i have created and replace the traditional building/office components with my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :
1. Export a part of open street map from their website. (go to the export tab) 
2. Use ElementTree in python to parse the exported the xml data. 
3. Use networkx to add the parsed data into a graph. 
4. Run your algorithms on it.